# DeprecationWarning: GraphicsWindow is deprecated, use GraphicsLayoutWidget instead

Tags: python, plot, deprecated

I cloned a github project (https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/AWR1843-Read-Data-Python-MMWAVE-SDK-3-.git) in order to use the Python visualiser so I can display in real time, data from AWR1843 radar (the radar has mmwave SDK 3 running on it, its the demo provided by TI). In fact the goal is to display in real time objects detected by a radar (the radar sends via USB data to visualiser)
After installing all the dependencies (pyserial, pyqtgraph etc.), I run the "readData_AWAR1843.py" file and I keep getting the following error :
"DeprecationWarning: GraphicsWindow is deprecated, use GraphicsLayoutWidget instead,will be removed in 0.13 win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="2D scatter plot")."
(and The window crashes)

Could you please help me out, because I tried to use "GraphicsLayoutWidget" and it runs the program but without doing or displaying anything at all (see picture below). Maybe I'am using GraphicsLayoutWidget the wrong way : How can I use GraphicsLayoutWidget instead of GraphicsWindow ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `win.show()` to display the layout that is created with `GraphicsLayoutWidget`. An example:

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MyApplication(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyApplication, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        bananas = [2, 6, 19, 29, 33, 45, 60, 70, 80, 96]

        self.win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget() # you added this 
        # self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow() you have removed this 
        self.win.resize(1000, 600)
        self.plot = self.win.addPlot(title='Working')

        self.curve = self.plot.plot()
        self.curve.setData(x=time, y=bananas)
        self.win.show() # you need to add this 


def main():
    app = MyApplication(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

FYI, it has been fixed in the GitHub script.